# Calling a Core Data attribute through a relationship

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, attributes, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two `Entities` as depicted in the image below:

[image]

`Food` and `Restaurant`.

I know the naming is a bit off for now, but basically, I'm building up a list of Food items. A user will add in a new entry with the name of the food and the name of the restaurant. I'm at the very early stages of development.

So in the `AddViewController`, and in the save method, I have:

```
if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
            foodEntry = FoodManagedObject(context: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)
            foodEntry.nameOfFood = foodNameTextField.text
            foodEntry.restaurantName?.nameOfRestaurant = restaurantNameTextField.text
```

With a variable declared:

var foodEntry:FoodManagedObject!

In the `TimelineView`, using `NSFetchedResultsController`, I'm fetching for the `FoodManagedObject` and able to display the name of the food in the label. However, the name of the restaurant doesn't display.

So, I'm fetching appropriately:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<FoodManagedObject> = FoodManagedObject.fetchRequest()
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nameOfFood", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
            fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

            do {
                try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
                if let fetchedObjects = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects {
                    foods = fetchedObjects
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

and in the `cellForRow`:

```
cell.foodNameLabel.text = foods[indexPath.row].nameOfFood

cell.restaurantLabel.text = foods[indexPath.row].restaurantName?.nameOfRestaurant
```

I get no errors, but the name of the restaurant never displays.

Foods is:

```
var foods:[FoodManagedObject] = []
```

So I've tried adding in an attribute called `theRestaurant` into the Food Entity and that works, but calling through a relationship never seems to work.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Do you ever create a `restaurantName` entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating relations between the objects, not of their values 
It means, that you must assign already existing restaurant entity object or create the new one when you're saving the new food object. 
You can't just assign object values without an initialisation of the restaurant object.

E.g.

```
foodEntry = FoodManagedObject(context: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)
foodEntry.nameOfFood = foodNameTextField.text

// Here you must to load existing Restaurant entity object from database or create the new one        
let restaurant = RestaurantManagedObject(context: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)
restaurant.nameOfRestaurant = restaurantNameTextField.text

foodEntry.restaurantName = restaurant // Object instead of value
```

Or if you already have some list of restaurants, than just add the new food object to one of them

Comment: oh wow.. thanks so much @livenplay - that really makes sense and with your guidance, I was able to get it working. I see the mistake - that you have to actually declare and assign for the restaurants entity and that's part of it, and then assign it to the relationship. It works like a charm now - thanks so much!